# How to add a MANIFEST file usig cmake and module UseJava?

Tags: java, cmake, manifest.mf

Goal is simple. adding a MANNIFEST file into final jar archive.

For this I read many documentation but i miss the right information. Finally I come to you to get some help, thanks in advance.

What I do ?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
find_package(Java REQUIRED)
include(UseJava)

enable_testing()
project(DAI)

set( cwd                            "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}"                           )
set( AIName                         "SkirmishDAI"                                                   )
set( SRC_DIR                        "${cwd}/src"                                            )
set( LIB_DIR                        "${cwd}/libs"                                           )

set( MAJOR_VERSION                  0                                                       )
set( MINOR_VERSION                  1                                                       )
set( PATCH_VERSION                  0                                                       )
set( VERSION                        "${MAJOR_VERSION}.${MINOR_VERSION}.${PATCH_VERSION}"    )

set( CMAKE_JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH        "${LIB_DIR}"                                            )
set( CMAKE_JAVA_COMPILE_FLAGS       "-source" "1.7" "-target" "1.7"                         )

set( DAI_JAR_NAME                   "${AIName}-${VERSION}.jar"                              )
set( DAI_JAR_FILE                   "${CMAKE_JAVA_TARGET_OUTPUT_DIR}/${DAI_JAR_NAME}"       )
set( DAI_MANIFEST                   "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"      )
configure_file("manifest.extras.in" "${DAI_MANIFEST}" @ONLY                                 )

FILE( GLOB_RECURSE JAVA_SRC_FILES   "${SRC_DIR}/main/java/*.java"                           )
FILE( GLOB_RECURSE JAVA_TEST_FILES  "${SRC_DIR}/test/java/*.java"                           )

add_jar( ${AIName} ${JAVA_SRC_FILES} ${JAVA_TEST_FILES} VERSION ${VERSION} MANIFEST ${DAI_MANIFEST} )
```

This will add into the jar file a manifest … but a wrong place.

That mean, when manifest go to **${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF**, I will get the same full path in the jar file intead of **META-INF/MANIFEST.MF**

jarfile

```
 /
 /com/cool/app/Main.class
 /mypath/to/bin/dir/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

while I expect to get

jarfile

```
 /
 /com/cool/app/Main.class
 /META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

**UPDATE**: Make run following command:

```
$ make VERBOSE=1
…
[ 31%] Creating Java archive SkirmishDAI-0.1.0.jar
cd /mnt/data/projects/spring/build/AI/Skirmish/DAI/CMakeFiles/SkirmishDAI.dir && /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.65-2.5.2.5.fc20.x86_64/bin/jar -cf /mnt/data/projects/spring/build/AI/Skirmish/DAI/SkirmishDAI-0.1.0.jar /mnt/data/projects/spring/build/AI/Skirmish/DAI/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF @java_class_filelist
cd /mnt/data/projects/spring/build/AI/Skirmish/DAI/CMakeFiles/SkirmishDAI.dir && /usr/bin/cmake -D_JAVA_TARGET_DIR=/mnt/data/projects/spring/build/AI/Skirmish/DAI -D_JAVA_TARGET_OUTPUT_NAME=SkirmishDAI-0.1.0.jar -D_JAVA_TARGET_OUTPUT_LINK=SkirmishDAI.jar -P /usr/share/cmake/Modules/UseJavaSymlinks.cmake.
…
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem likely stems from a duplicated path in the following lines:

```
set( DAI_MANIFEST                   "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"      )
configure_file("manifest.extras.in" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${DAI_MANIFEST}" @ONLY                             )
```

You probably meant:

```
set( DAI_MANIFEST                   "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"      )
configure_file("manifest.extras.in" "${DAI_MANIFEST}" @ONLY                             )
```

Comment: Thanks @sakra for your help. After a make clean / make i have always the same problem. But you are right line should to be as your show. That is one step to the solution.

Comment: For my case, I only have a currentDir/MANIFEST.MF, so first line of "set(...)" is enough for me.